# Another asymptote diagram doesn't display properly

Tags: asymptote

I'm trying to contruct this diagram:
[image]
I use the following code:

```
import cse5;
size(10cm);pair B=(-1,0),C=(1,0),D=(0,sqrt(3)),E=(0,1.2),F;
filldraw((0,sqrt(3))--(0,0)--C--arc(B,C,(0,sqrt(3)))--cycle,cyan);
xaxis(xmin=-4,xmax=2.5,arrow=Arrows);
yaxis(ymin=-2.5,ymax=2.5,arrow=Arrows);
draw(circle(B,2));draw(Arc(C,B,D,direction=CW));
path c1=circumcircle(B,C,E);
path c2=circle(B,2);
F=IP(c1,c2,0);
draw(arc(circumcenter(B,C,E),F,E),heavygreen);
pair A=relpoint(arc(circumcenter(B,C,E),F,E),0.7);
D(B--A--C);draw(B--E--C^^B--C,dotted);
dot(A^^B^^C^^D^^E^^F);label("$B$",B,SW);label("$C$",C,SE);label("$D$",D,2*W);
label("$A$",A,N);
```

But it produces this

[image]

Can someone please explain what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, perhaps you can read the asymptote `output`. Indeed `circumcircle` is not a basic asy routine. It is defined in the `geometry` extension. Add `import geometry;` and compile !

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Also, what are some popular Asymptote extension? I only know cse5 and graph.

Comment: You can try to read the documentation to have a list of the extensions, also the great tutorial of Charles Staats http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf